# Can the southeast areas in the Equipment Makers' Cellar be reached?

Tags: albion

In the 1995 game Albion, once you reach Umajo and head down to the Equipment Makers' cellar, there is a room to the southeast of the second floor that has windows revealing a storm demon. I can't seem to get into this room, though. [image]

There's also a door a level below (Kossotto's floor) at a good spot to let you potentially climb up into that room but it can't be opened by hand, and the nearby false wall only lets you get halfway there. [image]

In the version of the game available on GOG the debugging mode doesn't let you clip through walls, so I can't even use a cheat to try to figure out what the solution was supposed to be, and walkthroughs all seem to gloss over this cellar, telling you only how to get to the most interesting bits (Animal 3 blue plate, Stone of Visions, Kossotto).

Is there a way to get into that room with the storm demon, or the room above with the locked door?

Comment: Wow, that is a long time ago! I remember this. it was difficult to get there but it is possible. Could it be possible that there is a floor above it that allows you to go down into that room? (or is that somewhere else?). Sorry for the vague hint, I played this 17 years ago.

Comment: The floor above allows you to get to the 2nd level: L1 has stairs out, and stairs up too the little brown corridor in the southwest of L2, which in turn goes up to an L shaped corridor leading to a pit that drops you into the spinner room. None of the walls in the L shaped corridor are fake, so I'm not aware of anything else you can do on L3!
I also played it a couple of decades ago, re-playing now for the nostalgia. It's like $8 on GOG.

Comment: I also remembered I tried to get into some place (not sure if it is this one) for a long time, gave up, and finally returned and was able to open it. Perhaps someone else could explain a bit more.

Comment: I know these dungeons contain some inaccessible rooms, but no idea about this one. I'll check it.

Comment: Also the GOG DOSBox is badly configured (no surprise really) since Alt+F12 is actually a key combination for Speedlock. Simply press Ctrl+F1 and delete the combination and it will work. Or just download a Windows port of the game and get twice the 3D resolution. ;-)